# ViewPager No view found for id for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a view pager that has 3 tabs fragment hosted by a FragmentActivity.

What I am trying to do is to replace those fragments with a new one after clicking an item:

```
public class UserShopActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        UserItemsFragment.OnUserItemSelectedListener,
        UserCategoriesFragment.OnUserCategoriesSelectedListener,
        UserSelectedCategoryFragment.OnUserItemsSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.shop_pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);
}

 ...

    @Override
    public void onUserCategoriesSelected(String category_id) {
        UserSelectedCategoryFragment fragment = new UserSelectedCategoryFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.shop_container, fragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
}
}
```

However I got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070011
>   (com.ked.ai:id/shop_container) for fragment
>   UserSelectedCategoryFragment{40f7bcf0 #3 id=0x7f070011}

I already set a container id in `setContentView`'s viewpager which is the `shop_container`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shop_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shop_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

But it couldn't find the id. How do I replace this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't replace a fragment in `ViewPager` you need to implement `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to display fragments in view pager.

For more info:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Try changing to:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/shop_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/shop_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >




</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

change `onCreate` to:

```
public class UserShopActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        UserItemsFragment.OnUserItemSelectedListener,
        UserCategoriesFragment.OnUserCategoriesSelectedListener,
        UserSelectedCategoryFragment.OnUserItemsSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.shop_pager);


}
```

Comment: I already have that to display those 3 tabs. Now I am trying to invoke a new fragment outside the viewpager. Is this possible? or do I have an alternative?

Comment: so put framelayout out of view pager.

Comment: Still the same. I've edited the question. Pls check it. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Great! no more errors. But the replaced layout is overlapped. How to overcome this? I've changed replace with `add()` but no luck.

Comment: you can just set visibility of the view pager to invisible

Comment: Okay this might be too much to ask. I've managed to make it invisible, now I'm having trouble bringing it back when pressing back button. Anyway thank you for your working solution.